# Freeze after upgrading kernel to 3.13.0-66 (14.04) or 3.19.0-31 (15.04)

Tags: 14.04, boot, 15.04

Dell LAtitude E6430 with CPU Intel® Core™ i5-3210M, 64 bits, no longer boots after updating 14.04 LTS system to kernel 3.13.0-66. It hangs off after completion of the password.
Back to the 3.13.0-64 kernel works, but still with a system error, pending since about the beginning of the year (beginning approximately for the kernel 3.13.0-40) and never corrected by subsequent upgrades. It seems that the system 14.04 LTS is going worse and worse on this computer. Is there a solution ?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Answer (score 14):

Buggy versions of the Linux kernel were uploaded on October 7 to trusty-proposed and vivid-proposed. Corrected replacement packages are about to be uploaded - see [bug #1503655](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1503655).

- Version 3.13.0-66.107 (trusty) will be replaced by version 3.13.0-66.108
- Version 3.19.0-31.35 (vivid) will be replaced by version 3.19.0-31.36

The developer Luis Henriques has made the updated packages for amd64 systems available in advance; please see [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1503647/comments/7).

See also this answer: [Remove linux version 3.19.31](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682682/remove-linux-version-3-19-31/682684#682684)

*Update 2015-10-08:*

The corrected packages have now replaced the buggy ones in trusty-proposed and viviv-proposed.

Answer (score 10):

First of all kernel 3.19.0-31 is not available in any Ubuntu **stable** repositories.

You got it installed because you enabled `proposed` software source in System Settings -> Software & Updates.

It is not recommended and you did it at your own risk.

You can always boot with a previous kernel using grub menu. Then you can install Synaptic and remove `linux-image` and `linux-headers` packages of version 3.19.0-31.

Also I recommend to disable `proposed` and never enable it unless you know what are you doing!

[image]

After you do it make sure that meta-packages `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` for 15.04 or `linux-image-generic-lts-vivid` and `linux-headers-generic-lts-vivid` for 14.04.3 are installed.

Otherwise the kernel will not get normal upgrades.

To get into grub menu you need to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> at boot depending on your hardware.

Comment: your answer is mainly focused on repositories and not on how to remove that image

Comment: Thank you for this information. It turn out that 'Pre-released updates was already checked when I installed 15.04 and Synaptic successfully removed the new kernal.  All is good now.

Comment: This may be a question for a new thread, I don't know. Any idea when 15.10 is going to be released?

Answer (score 2):

Similar problem with my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, on Dell Inspiron n5040, Intel Pentium P6200, and the version of the kernel. My temporary solution is to reinstall this kernel, and now I'm working with previous version: 3.13.0-65.