# Remove linux version 3.19.31

Tags: kernel, updates, uninstall

My system was just updated with linux image 3.19.31. When it was rebooted, the system hang at the login screen and did nothing.  How can I remove this image? It has a major bug in it.

Comment: Also related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/682589/freeze-after-upgrading-kernel-to-3-13-0-66-14-04-or-3-19-0-31-15-04/682787#682787