# 15.04 update 09/07/2015 > How can I repair this catastrophe?

Tags: updates

An update on 09/07/2015 to 15.04 was a real catastrophe! Not only my computers crashed, all of my friends' computers as well. Ubuntu froze with normal BOOT! Mouse and keyboard functionality totally killed!

And now, how can we get rid of these bugs?

Clearly, it's a graphics driver problem, which probably could be solved with:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
```

But how can I get into the frozen update Version? When I start the automatic boot process, it always gets into the cracked version and freezes! Other later versions are working in poor or false graphic mode and I can start the routine above, so these versions are finally OK, but I can't put one of these working versions as Main-Version!

Comment: Which version were you running before? It sounds possibly like a driver incompatibility. You should probably boot from a LiveUSB/LiveCD to recover any data you need, and then try to reinstall a fresh install, if that does not work, perhaps you should downgrade to an LTS release which works for you.

Comment: Try from grub's root shell. You'll have to manually connect to your network in order to use `apt-get`.

Comment: This rant isn't the most effective way of getting any help. As you can tell by the downvotes, it's probably best to edit your question to just state the facts. I know it's frustrating when your system doesn't work, but this is a question/answer site where volunteers try to help. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove linux version 3.19.31](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682682/remove-linux-version-3-19-31)

Comment: Catastrophe is when the user clicks setting that are not supposed to be clicked.

Comment: Is the date 7th of September or 9th of July?

Comment: @Arronical: Probably the 7th of October. ;)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I genuinely just counted out the months of the year using my hands..... oh dear!

Answer (score 3):

Probably noone got money from Microsoft. But two mistakes were made:

1. You and your friends have the -proposed option enabled in "Software & Updates", which is not recommended.
2. [A buggy kernel version was uploaded to -proposed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682589/freeze-after-upgrading-kernel-to-3-13-0-66-14-04-or-3-19-0-31-15-04/682787#682787) by mistake.