# Problem to log after the last update of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, log

I'm using a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Yesterday I did an update of the system. Now I cannot open either the graphical part or the console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Maj</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). On the console, when I tape the password, the system is freezing, same with the graphical interface.

Surprisingly, I can connect to the guest session.

I restart the computer and go the grub option to open the old version (3.12.0-65) and the system is working fine.

I want to inform you that the 3.12.0-66 has a problem to log on a session.

Is someone can give me the process to ask Grub to launch the 3.12.0-65 automatically instead of the 3.12.0-66.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeze after upgrading kernel to 3.13.0-66 (14.04) or 3.19.0-31 (15.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682589/freeze-after-upgrading-kernel-to-3-13-0-66-14-04-or-3-19-0-31-15-04)

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you for your advices. I did the update to correct the bug and I enabled proposed software source as you recommend.

Comment: I suggested to DISABLE the proposed source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this problem because you enabled `proposed` software source.

Kernel 3.13.0-66 is in `proposed` repository and is not stable.

I recommend to disable proposed in System Settings to avoid this kind of problems.

`proposed` is for testing purposes, not for normal use.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fix**

Boot from 3.13.0-65 and just remove the problem kernel

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic
```

Update GRUB

```
sudo grub-update
```

**Better fix**

Alternatively if you would like to keep 3.13.0-66 you can edit this file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

You will need to know the number in which the kernel you want appears in the grub menu.

Example

```
0 Ubuntu with 3.13.0-66-generic

1 Advanced options for Ubuntu

2 Ubuntu with 3.13.0-65-generic
```

You can see in the example the kernel you want is the third one down, so number two because computers count from zero, in this example scenario you would

Find the line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` and change it too `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` to boot with `3.13.0-65-generic` by default.

Don't forget to update your grub

```
sudo grub-update
```

Comment: If this works for you (try it first) please press the check mark next to the answer so others can easily find it.

Comment: It is not 3.12, but 3.13.

Comment: @Pilot6 Indeed it would seem so, 3.12.0-66 does no exist, updateing