# ubuntu 14.04 lts doesn't boot since 3.13.0-64

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, crash

This is a DELL inspiron 3551, with Ubuntu 14.04 lts 64 bits preinstalled
processor: *Intel® Pentium(R) CPU N3540 @ 2.16GHz × 4*. Quickly after system update, it starts to crash when booting.

- I don't think it is a duplicate of [Freeze after upgrading kernel to 3.13.0-66 (14.04) or 3.19.0-31 (15.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682589/freeze-after-upgrading-kernel-to-3-13-0-66-14-04-or-3-19-0-31-15-04), since it doesn't freeze when login, it crashes as soon as it starts booting.
- Actually 3.13.0-64 never got installed. But 3.13.0-65,65,67 are installed, but crash when booting.
  I need to select 3.13.0-63 generic so it can boot.

I don't know much about Linux. I wanted to try it, that is why I choose a preinstalled Ubuntu. When it crashes, there is a bunch of text ending by kernel panic.

I don't know what information could be useful so you can help me.
Please tell me so and also how to obtain that information.

[image: a screenshot of the crash from september 15 after update to 3.13.0-63 here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Freeze after upgrading kernel to 3.13.0-66 (14.04) or 3.19.0-31 (15.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682589/freeze-after-upgrading-kernel-to-3-13-0-66-14-04-or-3-19-0-31-15-04)

Comment: thanks for suggesting this, I edited the thread cause I don't think it is the same issue