# Ubuntu 14.04.3 crashes after connecting with wifi

Tags: 14.04, networking, broadcom, crash

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Kernel Version 3.19.0-39-generic.

I can connect to the internet with Ethernet cable. When I switch to a fixed-ip wireless network, the computer freezes!

I have the wireless card BCM43227 from Broadcom. I thought it might be a driver problem so I did the following (since apparently Broadcom drivers are a bit buggy):

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

But it didn't work.

I've googled a lot and found that there were similar bugs (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1464738, [Freeze after upgrading kernel to 3.13.0-66 (14.04) or 3.19.0-31 (15.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/682589/freeze-after-upgrading-kernel-to-3-13-0-66-14-04-or-3-19-0-31-15-04)) recently which might be fixed (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1503647/comments/7).

Some of these bugs come from the proposed repositories, which I DO NOT have activated. Is this issue still a bug? or a wrong driver?

Any help will be appreciated :-)

**Edit 1: output from** `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43227 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4358]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e040]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

**Edit 2: tried solution from possible duplicate** [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

which means running the command

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

Unfortunately, it did not work. The system froze once again after connecting with the wireless network.

Note: this was the same driver that was installed after the fresh install that I did a few hours ago, or at least that's what I think since the system settings->software updates->additional drivers said I was using the proprietary drivers.

**Edit 3:**

After boot up, both the cable and wireless connection are connected. No system freeze.

Unplugged Ethernet cable, wireless connection still active. No system freeze.

The moment I tried to open the browser -->> system froze! :-(

I don't know what that means ... any thoughts?

**Edit 4: the log** `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25`

This is all I can get before the system freezes (unpluged Eth-Cable and browser was open):

```
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): device state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'carrier-changed')
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (eth0): deactivating device (reason 'carrier changed')
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <warn> DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Removing DNS information from /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec  8 09:03:37 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'GOE-WLAN'.
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Dec  8 09:03:44 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Dec  8 09:03:45 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Dec  8 09:03:45 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Dec  8 09:03:45 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Dec  8 09:03:45 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> NetworkManager statte is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Dec  8 09:03:45 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Policy set 'GOE-WLAN' (wlan0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dec  8 09:03:45 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Writing DNS  information to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  8 09:03:46 aguilar NetworkManager[996]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated
```

Log after boot up and before I open my browser:

```
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0/wireless) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'GOE-WLAN'.
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) scheduled.
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) started...
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Beginning IP6 addrconf.
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 3 of 5 (IP Configure Start) complete.
Dec  8 09:07:11 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Dec  8 09:07:12 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> secondaries (reason 'none') [70 90 0]
Dec  8 09:07:12 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Dec  8 09:07:12 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: error processing netlink message: Object busy
Dec  8 09:07:12 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Dec  8 09:07:13 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Dec  8 09:07:13 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Dec  8 09:07:12 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Dec  8 09:07:23 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: error processing netlink message: Object busy
Dec  8 09:07:24 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> (eth0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Dec  8 09:07:24 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Dec  8 09:07:24 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Dec  8 09:07:24 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (eth0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
Dec  8 09:07:30 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Dec  8 09:07:30 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Dec  8 09:07:30 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Dec  8 09:07:30 aguilar NetworkManager[838]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6: done. thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a proprietary driver. Run:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Nothing is buggy. You just did not install the correct driver.

Comment: thx but it did not work. I'm going to try the solution of the possible duplicate

Comment: It is the same solution. What did not work?

Comment: the system froze again after it connected to the wireless network

Comment: You did something wrong. Try to do a fresh install and install the same driver.

Comment: That driver was already installed after the fresh install I did this morning

Comment: That is weird. Do you install Mint or something else?

Comment: nop. I did the fresh install and one of the first things I did was setup the wireless network (ip fixed) which froze the system after the first try. With DHCP I can 'connect' and does not freeze the system but there is no internet because I need to set a fixed ip and gateway for that ...

Comment: This is not a driver issue. Something wrong with your network config.

Comment: mmm ok maybe ... but what? And even if it is, does a system freeze makes sense as a result of that? PS: Our network is configured to work that way (I mean with fixed IPs) and was working with Debian7

Comment: How do you configure network interface? Using NM or in `/etc/network/interfaces`? And you can see what happens in logs. Probably three is some simple mistake.

Comment: using the network manager

Comment: sry missed that with the logs ... how can I see what happens with the logs?

Comment: Check the log: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25`

Comment: @chili555 thx for the help. I made some edits

Comment: This is interesting: `<warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: error processing netlink message: Object busy` I'd like to see the syslog lines leading up to the crash and just after. Make a note of the time, let it crash and after a reboot, check and paste the surrounding 20 lines here: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 just paste them there? ok done. I pasted 4 sets of lines. The first two are duplicates (sry), which means three crashes ... There are some weird '@'  characters on two of the crashes. What do they mean?

Comment: After you paste them there, a link (URL) is created. We need the link address to see the output, please. For example: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13861422/

Comment: @chili555 oh man, sry! I got sick and then came the holidays! Happy new year by the way! I hope you can still help me :-) 
link 1: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14418323/
link 2: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14418345/
link 3: http://paste.ubuntu.com/14418351/